# Escape sequences in javascript

Tags: javascript, null, escaping

I know that there are escape sequences like \n \b etc in javascript as like in other programming languages.

alert(\j)=>alerts j ...So what is the role of \ here?.Which character is escaped?Is it null character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Special characters in JavaScript Strings include `'`, `"`, `\`, `n`, `r`, `t`, `b`, and `f`, as per [JavaScript Special Characters<sup>w3schools</sup>](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_special_characters.asp). Because `j` is *not* a special character and `\` *is* (must itself be escaped to be displayed), it would make sense that the `\` is simply ignored.

**`\` plays no role in `"\j"`.**

Answer (score 2):

None. `\j` isn't a recognized escape, so the escaping is ignored and "j" is used instead.

```
js> "\j"
"j"
```